# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'solarpic.gif'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, filenotfounderror

From a command prompt on Windows 11 with Python 3.8.10 I run the following pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "solarpic.gif;." scratch.py
```

`solarpic.gif` is in the same folder as `scratch.py`, but I get an exception that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "scratch.py", line 7, in <module>
    File "PIL\Image.py", line 3227, in open
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    'solarpic.gif'
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root=Tk()

picframe = LabelFrame(root)
picframe.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, 
pady=10,sticky=NSEW)
photo_image = Image.open('solarpic.gif')
img1 = photo_image.resize((600, 200))
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
piclabel = Label(picframe, image=photo_image)
piclabel.place(x=10,y=10)
piclabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried:

```
--add-data "solarpic.gif;."
--add-data "solarpic.gif;.gif"
--add-data "solarpic.gif;solarpic.gif"
```

Comment: When do you get the exception - is it when you try to create the application with Pyinstaller, or when you try to run it, or just what? What happened when you tried the other variants of the `pyinstaller` command?

Comment: Thanks for responding... The code compiles fine..no errors.  The error occurs when I run the executable. If I put the file that was not found in the same folder as the executable, everything works fine. The other variants responded with the same error.